# Facing issue with Dataweave transformation

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Background: In one of my application am storing the datetimestamp in object store. Now that app is decommissioned and business team want the last stored datetimestamp in object store. By using cloudhub API i have got the below response from the objectstore api.

{
"binaryValue": "++Kn0AIB5+z4uQQBMjAyMi0wMS0zMVQxNToyODozMy4yN7b8rNmhAQHn7Pi5BGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL2phdmE7IGNoYXJzZXQ9VVRGLbgAAAAAAAAAFw==",
"keyId": "lastSuccessRunTime",
"valueType": "BINARY"
}

Also the business team want me to show the datetime stamp using the dataweave playground

I am trying to convert the binary value in a readable format using dataweave. I have tried available option up to my knowledge but nothing worked out.

Can some one help here?

Here is the DW code:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Binaries
output application/json
var 
base64="++Kn0AIB5+z4uQQBMjAyMi0wMS0zMVQxNToyODozMy4yN7b8rNmhAQHn7Pi5BGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL2phdmE7IGNoYXJzZXQ9VVRGLbgAAAAAAAAAFw=="
---
fromBase64(base64)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the value supposed to contain? Note, you should use text for code, textual values and errors, not a screenshot. See the help for an explanation: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I also recommend strongly to read carefully the help for how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks @aled. I will follow the recommendations.

Comment: I suggest to explain what is the value from the objectstore, how it was stored there and clarify if it was transformed in any way. The DataWeave script seems to be working as expected. The problem may be at the source of the data.

Comment: How the value was stored originally in the object store? What was it's type and format?

Comment: I found a document for this-https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-decode-Object-Store-Key-value-in-Mule-4. Also doubt on the value of binary key , it looks very short to me, Can you check it again?

Comment: according to this document link-- https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-decode-Object-Store-Key-value-in-Mule-4     i tried to decode your binary value using https://www.base64decode.org/  but it seems like your binary value is not correct. because the binary value mentioned in the document was perfectly decoded

Comment: @AnuragSharma I am able decode the value by using only binaryvalue from above response. The link you shared is helpfull.

Comment: My understanding from the document was  decoding the Object Store key/value pairs to human-readable value is not allowed by Mulesoft. The proper way is to use the Object Store 'Retrieve' operation. I have used only below part for decoding using the external website[ https://www.base64decode.org/] and it returned me the same value:

"++Kn0AIB5+z4uQQBMjAyMi0wMS0zMVQxNToyODozMy4yN7b8rNmhAQHn7Pi5BGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL2phdmE7IGNoYXJzZXQ9VVRGLbgAAAAAAAAAFw=="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code that is only specific solution to your question, but I insist follow this link https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-decode-Object-Store-Key-value-in-Mule-4

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Binaries
output application/json
---
do {
    var decode= fromBase64(payload.binaryValue)
    var data= decode[(decode find "2")[0] + 1 to (decode find ".")[0] + 3]
    ---
    data
}
```

the output of this code is

```
"2022-01-31T15:28:33.27"
```

below is the snippet of the input/code/output
[image]

Note: The proper way is to use the Object Store 'Retrieve' operation if possible

Comment: I am trying to leverage data weave here to get the value in readable format but after you pitch-in i understood that its not possible.

Comment: yes you are right, but even though  if your client ask to showcase output in DWL playground then you can use this DWL code

Comment: Yes your code is usefull to do my demo. Thank you for helping out.